# graphics glitch with xorg on ubuntu 20.04 after update

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg

I've been using ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad t430s with intel graphics for around a year now with no problems. Yesterday, Ubuntu asked me to install an update. After the update, my graphics was suddenly extremely glitchy. Icons from the desktop flash through my browser, scrolling is inconsistent. Sometimes graphics breaks down altogether and I have to restart the laptop.

The problems are worse in xorg. Switching to Ubuntu on Wayland makes it *usable* (although still glitchy), but xorg is terrible. I tried

```
sudo apt purge install xserv-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get install xserv-xorg-video-intel
```

but xorg is still as glitchy as ever. Wayland is usable, but still having problems (for example, rendering features of my firefox add-ons).

I believe I have the T430s with only intel graphics.

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

yields

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:33 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can fix this?
Otherwise, I am going to have to reinstall everything and probably restart with 18.04.

Comment: Are you using any graphics driver PPA?

Comment: Purging and reinstalling xserver-xorg-video-intel and rebooting seems to help, but I think it's only a matter of time before the glitches start up again.

Comment: How does it work when removing xserver-xorg-video-intel? Then you will be using the kernel mode drivers for the Intel. Alternatively, if it worked before, you may be using the hwe kernel (i.e latest) where you may be better off with the LTS kernel (older but long support). Look at `uname -a` to see your kernel version.

Comment: First off, vanadium is a great element! Interesting spin dynamics in some of its complexes. Secondly, it was completely unusable with xserver-xorg-video-intel removed. Reinstalling it seemed to improve things somewhat, but I am still having some glitches (e.g., the desktop icons flash through my browser when I scroll in Firefox). Everything worked perfectly before I installed the latest software update. uname -a gives:

Linux MyComputer 5.8.0-49-generic #55~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 26 01:01:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I have the same problem here since last update.
It seems I have the same or similar graphic chip on a HP Elitebook 8470.
Worked like a charm before.
Switched to wayland and it seems a little better, but I'm not happy at all with the situation. I've filed a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe-5.8/+bug/1924624

Comment: It seemed fine for a little while when I switched to Wayland, but then it got WAY worse. For now, I've switched back to Xorg and I'm dealing with the glitches. It seems that they get worse over time, as the session runs. But yeah, it was definitely the update. I recall being prompted to install the update for like a week, and I kept putting it off. After I finally installed the update, eveyrthing began to go wrong.